# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status in angular

Tags: python, angular, flask, cors

i'm developing a website with angular as and flask as backend, i've used flask-cors on backend and have set up proxy on frontend using tutorial on this link [https://www.positronx.io/handle-cors-in-angular-with-proxy-configuration/#:~:text=Enable%20CORS%20with%20Proxy%20Configuration%20Settings%20in%20Angular.&text=To%20enable%20CORS%20via%20proxy,the%20deliberate%20use%20of%20SSL](https://www.positronx.io/handle-cors-in-angular-with-proxy-configuration/#:%7E:text=Enable%20CORS%20with%20Proxy%20Configuration%20Settings%20in%20Angular.&text=To%20enable%20CORS%20via%20proxy,the%20deliberate%20use%20of%20SSL).

but I always get an error like the following. Please help me solve this problem, thanks

error : `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

**the following is the program code for angular**

proxy.conf.json [this is where i setting the proxy]

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

backend-api-service.ts [this is where i put all the API services]

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Login } from '../model/login';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BackendAPIService {
  private baseAPI = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/"

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  readCSVForecastFile(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseAPI + 'forecast/4b4315e0-1cb2-4595-9124-99fefa9c63f4/read')
    .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

  login(post: Login): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.post(this.baseAPI + 'login', JSON.stringify(post), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.errorHandler)
    )
  }

  errorHandler(error:any) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    return throwError(errorMessage);
 }

}
```

login.ts

```
export class Login {
    email!: string;
    password!: string;
}
```

login.component.ts  [this is my login component, when i try to login, the error always appear]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BackendAPIService } from 'src/app/services/backend-api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form!: FormGroup ;

  logindata = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }

  private en = {
    'lable_emailaddress': 'Email Address',
    'leble_enterpassword': 'Enter Password',
    'input_email' : 'Email',
    'input_password' : 'Password',
    'hyperlink_forgotpassword': "Forgot Password?",
    'button_login': "Login",
    'button_register': 'Register',
    'or' : 'Or'
  }

  private idn = {
    'lable_emailaddress': 'Alamat Email',
    'leble_enterpassword': 'Ketikkan Kata Sandi',
    'input_email' : 'Email',
    'input_password' : 'Kata Sandi',
    'hyperlink_forgotpassword': "Lupa Kata Sandi?",
    'button_login': "Masuk",
    'button_register': 'Daftar',
    'or' : 'Atau'
  }


  used_lang = {
    'lable_emailaddress': '',
    'leble_enterpassword': '',
    'input_email' : '',
    'input_password' : '',
    'hyperlink_forgotpassword': "",
    'button_login': "",
    'button_register': '',
    'or' : ''
  }

  constructor(private backendAPI: BackendAPIService, private router: Router) { 
    this.language('idn')
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }

  title!: "Login";

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const isLogin = this.isLogin();
    window.onload = function(){
      if(isLogin == '201'){
        document.getElementById('form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }
  }


  submit(){
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.backendAPI.login(this.form.value).subscribe(res => {
         console.log('Post created successfully!');
         this.router.navigateByUrl('register');
    })
  }


  login(): void{
    const data = {
      email: this.logindata.email,
      password: this.logindata.password
    }

  }

  isLogin(): String{
    // contoh aja
    return '202'
  }

  language(lang:string){
    if(lang === 'idn'){
      this.used_lang = {...this.idn};
    } else {
      this.used_lang = {...this.en};
    }
  }
  

}
```

login.component.html   [this is the html file]

```
<form class="form-body" id="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <label for="inputEmailAddress" class="form-label">{{used_lang.lable_emailaddress}}</label>
      <div class="ms-auto position-relative">
        <div class="position-absolute top-50 translate-middle-y search-icon px-3"><i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control radius-30 ps-5" id="inputEmailAddress"
          placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <label for="inputChoosePassword" class="form-label">{{used_lang.leble_enterpassword}}</label>
      <div class="ms-auto position-relative">
        <div class="position-absolute top-50 translate-middle-y search-icon px-3"><i class="bi bi-lock-fill"></i></div>
        <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control radius-30 ps-5" id="inputChoosePassword"
          placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-end"><a href="authentication-forgot-password.html">{{used_lang.hyperlink_forgotpassword}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="d-grid">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary radius-30">{{used_lang.button_login}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <p class="mb-0">{{used_lang.or}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="d-grid">
        <a class="btn btn-success radius-30" href="/register">{{used_lang.button_register}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**the following is the program code for Flask**

app.py [this is my flask file for the backend]

```
from flask import Flask, abort, jsonify, redirect, request, flash, url_for, render_template, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required,LoginManager,current_user

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='Templates')
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@cross_origin()
def login_post():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if not user and not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            return 'Please check your login details and try again.',400

        login_user(user)

        return jsonify(current_user.id),200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.port = 5000
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Those errors are usually serverside issue, can you try use `CORS(app)` that allows all methods and origins, if that works you know you need to adjust your cors settings.

Comment: also what is this `app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'` if it was intended as actual cors headres content-type is not one of them, its usually just POST PUT GET DELETE etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS should be server-side issue, not Angular.

Anw just for development purposes you can open Chrome with the option --disable-web-security. You can check the ref here: [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)